# .NET CF DataGrid repaints without OnPaint firing?

Tags: .net, datagrid, custom-controls, compact-framework

Recently asked a related question, about double-buffering in .NET Compact Framework when painting over a base control's painting, and I noticed another issue that was causing some flickering.

My grid control, which inherits from DataGrid, overrides OnPaint to do some custom painting, on top of the base DataGrid's painting, and while some events cause OnPaint to fire (like CurrentCellChanged), some other events (KeyPress event, MouseDown event from clicking but not changing current cell, or ValueChanged event for the 2 scrollbars) cause the base DataGrid to repaint but OnPaint isn't fired (so for a split second, the DataGrid looks like a normal DataGrid, without my custom headers).

Is there a good way to prevent this?

Currently what I did is just manually redo painting in each of the event handlers for those events that paint the basic DataGrid without OnPaint firing.  This just feels like a bad solution, and occassionally there is still a bit of flicker. (like if I scroll vertically through an 800 row grid it flickers maybe 5 times).

Comment: Yea when the DataGrid (in CF) receives a scroll event it triggers a redraw, bypassing the OnPaint method. The only way to not get left out of the loop is to use reflection to get the scroll controls and hook in your own handler.